# I am trying to use $project in pipeline of my aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

`$project` stage does'nt seem correct

i tried using `$match` and `$project` in my pipeline but its giving me the result as `$project` stage does'nt seem correct

```
var pipeline=[
    {$match: {
        genres:{ $nin:['Crime','Horror'] }
    }},
    {$project: {
        title:1,
        rated:1
    }}
]
```

Comment: Please provide further information. What do your documents look like? What result are you expecting? What result are you getting instead? Without this information we won't be able to help you very much.

Comment: @B.Fleming i actually want to get the documents which are having genres as either crime or horror and in those document i want to show only title and rated fields.I tried using $match and $project as mentioned above but when i try to execute it shows me "PROJECT STAGE DOES'NT MATCH".I guess there is something wronge in my project stage but i am not able to figure it out

Comment: Please provide more context. Add exact error messages. Show some example documents. Give the exact query you're using. At the very least, copy and paste the exact text of the error message and query in their entirety. You're showing what you think is helpful, but what is actually helpful might be hidden elsewhere.